# Selective Submission of form using <button> tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, button

I want a function to take some values from a form as input and manipulate in the background . I tried but it goes to a url `mydomain.com/gtype=selected` value . I just want it to do something in the background and not change the url

I have a fiddle over here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/4qppX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return false` in your `onclick` handler.

```
<button onclick="hihi(this.form.gtype); return false">sub</button>
```

An alternative is to make the button a [non-submitting button](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/button/) by saying `type="button"`

```
<button type="button" onclick="hihi(this.form.gtype);">sub</button>
```

I am not sure about the reasoning for this by the [W3C states](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button#States_of_the_type_attribute):

> If the element has a form owner, the element must submit the form owner from the button element.

Comment: By returning false, you are telling the form to not submit. If you returned true, then it would submit. Alternatively, you could make the button `type="button"` to make it a non-submitting button.

Comment: So is it like any button in a form is by default a submitting button? Isn't this different from the     input type=submit ?

Comment: I don't know why it's the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make sure your button is just a button, and not a "submit" control:

```
<button type='button' onclick='hihi(this.form.gtype)'>sub</button>
```

Comment: ok got it. I read it on w3cschools now.
Always specify the type attribute for the button. The default type for Internet Explorer is "button", while in other browsers (and in the W3C specification) it is "submit"